# How to link multiple scripts with a button in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a program in Python `Tkinter`, and I have a `main.py` and the `studio.py`.

And I want to connect them.The `main.py` is the menu and it has a button to go the studio.

So I want to navigate from the `main.py` to the `studio.py`.

Can anyone help me pls?

I tried every guide I found, but none of them worked.

Comment: Please provide a clear description of what you're trying to achieve and some minimal code samples of your two files. Do you want to launch studio.py as separate process when the button is clicked or display a Toplevel window or other widget defined in `studio.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm grateful to answer your question, and I hope you're having a beautiful day. :D

I hope I understood your question, in this case you need to import the script structure into the main script, and use the methods and classes in the main script. You can do this importing your secondary script in the main one, example:

```py
#Main script

import theSecondaryScript
```

## Example

Here's an expanded explanation on connecting main.py and studio.py in Python Tkinter:

**1. Structure your code:**

- **main.py:**

  - Create the main window (`main_window`) and menu elements.
  - Define a function (e.g., `open_studio`) to handle the button click that will open the studio window.
  - Organize your code into classes or functions for better readability and maintainability.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import studio  # Import the studio module

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main_window = tk.Tk()  # Create the main Tkinter window
        self.create_menu()
        self.create_button()

    def create_menu(self):
        # Add your menu elements here
        pass

    def create_button(self):
        button = tk.Button(self.main_window, text="Go to Studio", command=self.open_studio)
        button.pack()

    def open_studio(self):
        studio.create_studio_window()  # Call the studio window function

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_app = MainWindow()
    main_app.main_window.mainloop()
```

- **studio.py:**

  - Create the studio window (`studio_window`) and its contents.

```py
import tkinter as tk

def create_studio_window():
    studio_window = tk.Tk()  # Create a new Tkinter window for the studio
    # Add your studio window elements here
    studio_window.mainloop()  # Start the studio window's event loop
```

**2. Import the necessary module:**

- In main.py, import the studio module:

```py
import studio
```

**3. Create the button and link it to the function:**

- In main.py, create the button and bind it to the `open_studio` function:

```py
button = tk.Button(main_window, text="Go to Studio", command=open_studio)
button.pack()
```

**4. Define the `open_studio` function:**

- In main.py, define the function to open the studio window:

```py
def open_studio():
    studio.create_studio_window()  # Call the studio window function
```

**5. Create the studio window:**

- In studio.py, define the function to create the studio window:

```py
def create_studio_window():
    studio_window = tk.Tk()  # Create a new Tkinter window for the studio
    # Add your studio window elements here
    studio_window.mainloop()  # Start the studio window's event loop
```

### Result:

**main.py**

```py
import tkinter as tk
import studio

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main_window = tk.Tk()  # Create the main Tkinter window
        self.create_menu()
        self.create_button()

    def create_menu(self):
        # Add your menu elements here
        pass

    def create_button(self):
        button = tk.Button(self.main_window, text="Go to Studio", command=self.open_studio)
        button.pack()

    def open_studio(self):
        studio.create_studio_window()  # Call the studio window function

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_app = MainWindow()
    main_app.main_window.mainloop()
```

**studio.py**

```py
import tkinter as tk

def create_studio_window():
    studio_window = tk.Tk()  # Create a new Tkinter window for the studio
    # Add your studio window elements here
    studio_window.mainloop()  # Start the studio window's event loop
```

## Key points:

- Use `import` to access code from other modules.
- The `command` option of buttons specifies which function to call when clicked.
- Create a new Tkinter window for the studio using `tk.Tk()`.
- Call `mainloop()` on each window to start their event loops.

If you want to see a real example of linking multiple scripts using python, you can see this one: https://github.com/Gato-Capitao/LoomyPad/blob/main/LoomyPad.py

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me i hope you have a great day :)